# Argument list too long for ls while moving files from one dir to other in bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, centos, redhat

Below is the command I am using for moving files from dir `a` to dir `b`

```
  ls /<someloc>/a/* | tail -2000 | xargs -I{} mv {} /<someloc>/b/
    -bash: /usr/bin/ls: Argument list too long
```

folder `a` has files in millions ..

Need your help to fix this please.

Comment: As a general comment: [never parse the output of ls or find](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: @kvantour    Sure. Will keep in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the locations of both directories are on the same disk/partition and folder `b` is originally empty, you can do the following

```
$ rmdir /path/to/b
$ mv /other/path/to/a /path/to/b
$ mkdir /other/path/to/a
```

If folder `b` is not empty, then you can do something like this:

```
find /path/to/a/ -type f -exec mv -t /path/to/b {} +
```

If you just want to move 2000 files, you can do

```
find /path/to/a/ -type f -print | tail -2000 | xargs mv -t /path/to/b
```

But this can be problematic with some filenames. A cleaner way would be is to use `-print0` of `find`, but the problem is that `head` and `tail` can't process those, so you have to use `awk` for this.

```
# first 2000 files (mimick head)
find /path/to/a -type f -print0        \
  | awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\0"}(NR<=2000)' \
  | xargs -0 mv -t /path/to/b

# last 2000 files (mimick tail)
find /path/to/a -type f -print0        \
  | awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\0"}{a[NR%2000]=$0}END{for(i=1;i<=2000;++i) print a[i]}' \
  | xargs -0 mv -t /path/to/b
```

Comment: I want 20k data to move from folder `a` to folder `b` and yes both the folders are in same location. Note that folder `a` has files in millions..

Comment: how to use `tail` or `head` to move only limited files .. Sorry I am not from unix background..

Comment: No, that's what my original  command is doing , moving limited files .. So need help on that :)

Comment: Any sequence is fine for me, I am preparing some test data on folder `b` randomly

Comment: Modern versions of [head](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/head.1.html) and [tail](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) have a `-z` (`--zero-terminated`) option that allows them to handle the output of `find ... -print0`.

Answer (score 1):

The `ls` in the code in the question does nothing useful.  The glob (`/<someloc>/a/*`) produces a sorted list of files, and `ls` just copies it (after re-sorting it), if it works at all.  See [“Argument list too long”: How do I deal with it, without changing my command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/45583/264812) for the reason why `ls` is failing.

One way to make the code work is to replace `ls` with `printf`:

```
printf '%s\n' /<someloc>/a/* | tail -2000 | xargs -I{} mv {} /<someloc>/b/
```

`printf` is a Bash builtin, so running it doesn't create a subprocess, and the "Argument list too long" problem doesn't occur.

This code will still fail if any of the files contains a newline character in its name.  See the answer by kvantour for alternatives that are not vulnerable to this problem.